# Complex Grid Implementation in meteor(blaze)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

First let me explain schema of my collections.
I have 3 collections
company,deal,price
I want to use information from all three collection and make a single reactive,responsive table. Here is the image 
[image]

Now the schema for price collection is like this

```
{
  "_id" : "kSqH7QydFnPFHQmQH",
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-10-11T11:49:50.241Z"),
  "dealId" : "X5zTJ2y675PjmaLMx",
  "deal" : "Games",
  "price" : [{
      "type" : "worth",
      "value" : "Bat"
    }, {
      "type" : "Persons",
      "value" : 4
    }, {
      "type" : "Cost",
      "value" : 5
    }],
  "company" : "Company1"
}
```

Schema for company collection is

```
{
  "_id" : "da2da"
  "name" : "Company1"
}
```

Schema for deal collection is

```
{
  "_id" : "X5zTJ2y675PjmaLMx",
  "name" : "Games"
}
```

For each company there will be 3 columns added in table(worth,persons,cost)
For each deal there will be a new row in table.

As the information is coming from 3 collections into a single table. First I want to ask is it wise to make a table from 3 different collections? If yes how could I do that in blaze?
If no. Then I will have to make table from price collection only . What should be schema of this collection in best way. 
P.S in both cases I want to make table reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) for publishing related collections.

Secondly there is no intrinsic problem in setting up a table like this, you'll first figure out which collection to loop over with your `{{#each}}` in spacebars and then you'll define helpers that return the values from the related collections to your templates.

As far as your schema design, the choice as to whether to use nesting within a collection vs. using an entirely separate collection is typically driven by size. If the related object is overall "small" then nesting can work well. You automatically get the nested object when you publish and query that collection. If otoh it's going to be "large" and/or you want to avoid having to update every document when something in the related object changes then a separate collection can be better.

If you do separate your collections then you'll want to refer to objects from the other collection by `_id` and not by `name` since names can easily change. For example in your price collection you'd want to use `companyId: "da2da"` instead of `company: "Company1"`